# docker-compose build --no-cache not working

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run docker-compose build of my docker container with --no-cache flag to ignore caches and rebuild everything cause I need to re-run my maven build step.

However, it always use caches no matter what I do.

I tried:

- docker system prune -a -f
- docker builder prune

However, it always tries to use caches.

Here's the output from my terminal:

```
nikola@Nikolas-MacBook-Pro-2 trunk % docker builder prune
WARNING! This will remove all dangling build cache. Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
ID                      RECLAIMABLE SIZE        LAST ACCESSED
m8heul842dm3x8rp8m3tbudhb*                  true        0B          38 seconds ago
tf0scd9yisaqp0hz4cr9qfggu*                  true    1.447kB     38 seconds ago
q4xjz19cpi6svewufrkyhq2kg*                  true    0B          38 seconds ago
s7025dkjknbyfxa22mzzaw632*                  true    1.855kB     38 seconds ago
rdaco35lv54bnt4tpxhyadbvu*                  true    355B        38 seconds ago
hteoskb0az82vl4atz2jxc316*                  true    1.082MB     38 seconds ago
dda9gb78osodccckhwy7tc6tb*                  true    13.93MB     38 seconds ago
Total:  15.02MB
nikola@Nikolas-MacBook-Pro-2 trunk % docker-compose build news-service --build-arg PLATFORM=linux/amd64 --no-cache
[+] Building 2.8s (19/20)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.94kB                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for quay.io/wildfly/wildfly:27.0.1.Final-jdk17                                                                                                                                                         0.9s
 => https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.6.0.jar                                                                                                                                                                      1.7s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => => transferring context: 13.96MB                                                                                                                                                                                                0.1s
 => CANCELED [ 1/15] FROM quay.io/wildfly/wildfly:27.0.1.Final-jdk17@sha256:8470bc822820e17f7ecb5dc0c02ee9dbe1cdbcc885902253906a682a2d1688de                                                                                        1.8s
 => => resolve quay.io/wildfly/wildfly:27.0.1.Final-jdk17@sha256:8470bc822820e17f7ecb5dc0c02ee9dbe1cdbcc885902253906a682a2d1688de                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => sha256:8470bc822820e17f7ecb5dc0c02ee9dbe1cdbcc885902253906a682a2d1688de 743B / 743B                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => sha256:a5b4f7f4945b6574db7606dd8175f85a5dd7298b6ffe9cf5c9c19237d76a0efe 1.79kB / 1.79kB                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => sha256:e8e145a3c6b422ddab5ef5c7a7042c4dec36d5b84c1666cefff20d4d32219347 8.50kB / 8.50kB                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => sha256:2d473b07cdd5f0912cd6f1a703352c82b512407db6b05b43f2553732b55df3bc 1.05MB / 76.10MB                                                                                                                                     1.8s
 => => sha256:50e770a96dde57a5e5a0aa14457724aedca48015617007464fb8d5d08e84cedb 1.05MB / 18.78MB                                                                                                                                     1.8s
 => => sha256:c9c96d24fc74f9910704c0fcff09bd6f573c86af6ae88f4e7fdf04efc2e52ffe 5.24MB / 192.44MB                                                                                                                                    1.8s
 => CACHED [ 2/15] RUN yum -y install wget                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/15] RUN wget https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.9.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.9.3-bin.tar.gz -P /tmp   && tar xf /tmp/apache-maven-3.9.3-bin.tar.gz -C /opt   && ln -s /opt/apache-maven-3.9.3 /opt/maven    0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/15] ADD https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.6.0.jar /tmp/postgresql-42.6.0.jar                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/15] WORKDIR /tmp                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/15] COPY input_files/wildfly-command.sh ./                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/15] COPY input_files/module-install.cli ./                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [ 8/15] RUN sed -i -e 's/\r$//' ./wildfly-command.sh                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [ 9/15] RUN chmod +x ./wildfly-command.sh                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [10/15] RUN ./wildfly-command.sh     &&  rm -rf /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history/                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [11/15] COPY pom.xml ./                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [12/15] COPY src ./src/                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [13/15] RUN mvn clean package -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => ERROR [14/15] ADD target/cryptonews-2.3.2-debug.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/                                                                                                                                  0.0s
------
 > [14/15] ADD target/cryptonews-2.3.2-debug.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/:
------
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref moby::joy05flsq4q5cib1n5e0hot1j: "/target/cryptonews-2.3.2-debug.war": not found
```

Platform: MacOS 12.5

Comment: Just to be sure: the error you get has nothing to do with the cache. `ADD` expects a file in your local folder but you're generating it in the Dockerfile if I'm reading correctly.

Comment: If you `COPY` a file into the image (like your source code) and it's different from the previous build, Docker will automatically stop using the cache.  You shouldn't normally need `--no-cache` (it's not obvious why it's not working here, but it won't solve the problem @GaëlJ indicates).

Comment: @GaëlJ the problem is that mvn clean package should build a new file, cause ther version part of the war name has changed, however docker is using the cache so I only get cached version of the war which has the old version number in its name. That's why it is missing that file on ADD operation

Comment: No, that's not why the ADD fails. Replace your ADD with a `RUN ls target/` and/or `RUN CP target/*.war /opt/jboss...` to convince yourself. I mean maybe the filename is wrong but that's not the issue you're currently experiencing.